# How to identify parts of a vector image on Gslides in apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I'd like to work with vector images on slides. Using chrome developer tools to find the id of the various shapes making up an image is just not practical - can anyone suggest a better method?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `identify parts of a vector image on Gslides in apps script`. Can I ask you about the details of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for considering my problem. I intend to use vector graphics such as SVG, which are made up of a series on shapes. It is these shapes I'll be manipulating. I can get the shape ID's I need using Chrome Developer Tools, but the process is laborious for complex images.
Incidentally, identifying the shapes requires the slide ID. I can get this from the slide's URL - my technique works form normal slides but fails when targetting shapes on master slides.
Any ideas about this last problem would be really helpful. My project relies on using the master slide so I'm at an impasse at present.

Comment: Here's a video showing what I'm trying to achieve. The video shows the same project but using VBA in Powerpoint rather than Apps script in Google slides. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc7iGEDupEU

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I couldn't see your video, do you want to retrieve a shape in a Google Slide using Google Apps Script?

Comment: Apologies about the video, the upload defaulted to private not unlisted (now changed). In answer to your question, yes - I’m trying to manipulate the visibility/colour of objects such as shapes on the master slide.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could see your video. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do with your video. But, from `In answer to your question, yes - I’m trying to manipulate the visibility/colour of objects such as shapes on the master slide.`, in this case, I think that you can modify the shape color. But, I cannot still imagine your expected result. So, I cannot still propose a sample script. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Thanks for persevering with this. The video was just for background, so you had some idea of the context. I'm sure I'll be able to create the script I need once I've cleared up this particular problem. I want to manipulate images on a master slide.  When I do this with a normal slide I use SlidesApp.getActivePresentation() to select the presentation, getSlideById('id from url') to select the slide and getPageElementById('ID from Chrome Dev Tools') to select the shape. This does not work when I try the same thing with a shape on a master slide.

Comment: Think I've sorted it. I just needed to refer to the masterSlideLayouts array instead of using trying to use the id from the url. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've sorted it. I just needed to refer to the masterSlideLayouts array instead of using trying to use the id from the url.